# In how many shortest ways can we reach from the point

Tags: combinatorics

In how many shortest ways can we reach from the point (0,0,0) to the point (3,7,11) incspace where the movement is restricted to the X-Axis , Y-Axis and the Z-Axis or parallel to them and changing the axis is only permissible at integral points.( An integral point is one, which has coordinate as integer.)

I found out the total path to be covered as 21, am clueless as to what to do next... 
Note: I discussed this question with my teacher... he assumed that we always begin with the X-Axis. But such a condition is mentioned nowhere in the problem...

Comment: What do you mean by "shortest ways"? If you mean (in a loose sense) that you can only increase your coordinate (i.e. you cannot go "backwards" along an axis), and cannot pass by $(3,7,11)$, this reduces to a fairly easy to understand combinatorics problem related to directed graphs, for instance.

Comment: If it is indeed the case that my  understanding of your problem is  right, then this amounts to a three-dimensional extrapolation of this one problem I answered here -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143268/in-how-many-different-ways-can-i-get-from-a-to-b/3143276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how many unit moves we have to make on each of the axes in order to get to (3,7,11). We will have to make 3 Xs, 7 Ys, and 11 Zs. Now consider the number of ways to order them. Does it make a difference what order it is in? After some thought, we find that it doesn't make a difference.

In short, the problem reduces to the number of ways to order XXXYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZ. This reduces down to (21 C 7,3,11) = 465585120.